# Threading functions with VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to thread my functions so the main GUI of my application doesn't fail to respond while the tasks are running.

At the moment my form1.vb is something like this.  I've cut it down as to reduce the text, but everything works fine:

```
Public Class MAIR

Private Sub InstallTheAgent_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles InstallTheAgent.Click
    InstallAgentWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub InstallAgentWorker_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles InstallAgentWorker.DoWork
'Do some stuff
End Sub

Private Sub InstallAgentWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles InstallAgentWorker.RunWorkerCompleted
    ' Called when the BackgroundWorker is completed.
    MsgBox("Installation of the Agent Complete")
    ProgressBar1.Value = 0
End Sub

End Class
```

From my understanding, when the button "Open" is pressed, it calls the function Install and it should start this off in a separate thread, however this doesn't work.

This seems to work, but the GUI still locks up, suggesting its not in a separate thread

Comment: Is there a reason you've chosen this method specifically or was this the first method you saw that made sense when you started?

Comment: I just googled vb.net threads and it too me to the MSDN site on how to create background threads so my GUI doesn't crash

Comment: Righty-o. Answer with alternative method and documentation coming up shortly.

Comment: There's no point in using a thread.  Shell() is ancient history, use the .NET Process class instead.  It has an Exited event to let you know when the process completed.

Comment: @HansPassant Could you give me an example of how to run the same shell commands as a .net process?

Comment: Use the MSDN Library article for the Process class, it has good example code.

Comment: @HansPassant Process.Start("psexec.exe \\Machine -s \\blah-blah-blah)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using the [BackgroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to implement this kind of basic threading. You don't have a lot going on here so the basic implementation should suffice. Here is a snippet of how I would go about doing it. My method is a bit too complex (I have base classes and events wired up to catch a lot of worker events) to list here succinctly, so I'll abbreviate.

```
Public Class MAIR

    Dim worker as BackgroundWorker

    Private Sub Open_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Open.Click
        worker.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Worker_DoWork(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as DoWorkEventArgs)
        Call Shell("psexec.exe", AppWinStyle.Hide, True)       
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Worker_ProgressChanged(Byval sender as Object, ByVal e as ProgressChangedEventArgs)
        ' You can track progress reports here if you use them
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(Byval sender as Object, ByVal e as RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
        ' Report back to the main application that the thread is completed
    End Sub

    Private Sub Install_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)     Handles MyBase.Load
        worker = New BackgroundWorker()

        ' Add the event wire-ups

        ' ### This event wire-up establishes the link
        ' ### that is used by RunWorkerAsync to initiate
        ' ### the code you want to run asynchronously
        AddHandler worker.DoWork, AddressOf Worker_DoWork

        AddHandler worker.ProgressChanged, AddressOf Worker_ProgressChanged
        AddHandler worker.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf Worker_RunWorkerCompleted
    End Sub

End Class
```

This is all translated from C#, so treat it as psuedo-code. The important piece is the documentation of the BackgroundWorker and its behaviors. There is a lot of terrific functionality in this class that takes the headaches of threads away for simple usages. This class is located in `System.ComponentModel` so you'll need the reference and an `Imports` statement.

**Edit:** Something I forgot to mention is that once the worker is fired asynchronously, the only manner of tracking it or communicating with the main application is through the `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted` events. No global variables or cross-thread items will be available, so you'll have to use the built-in properties to pass in any values (such as computerName it looks like) that you may need during the run.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not sure if this will affect things, however in the Public Class MAIR,  I have several buttons functions which call other functions, one after another.   So 1 function to install and then 1 to run something - Clicking the button will call the install function and then the run function.

Comment: @GregHesp: This just becomes a matter of sequencing. It could mean a series of actions to prepare the threaded task or sequencing them to wait for each one to complete before pressing on to the next or even potentially multiple BackgroundWorkers to handle all of the actions asynchronously.

Comment: Not sure if I've missed something, but I'm failing to see how worker.RunWorkerAsync() calls Sub Worker_DoWork

Comment: @GregHesp: It's part of the implementation. When you call the `RunWorkerAsync()` method, the worker fires off the `DoWork` event. This event needs to be "caught", which is why I have it wired to be handled as a delegate in `MyBase.Load` portion of this example. Basically, the worker initiates it, your code catches it. *ps* I added a couple of notes in that method to highlight the `DoWork` delegate.

Comment: I *think* you need to add `worker.WorkerReportsProgress = True` and `worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True` for those events to actually get called.  The defaults are False.

Comment: I take it I can just have one worker for all my functions (as they dont run at the same time) and just change the part AddHandler worker.DoWork, AddressOf Worker_DoWork, AddressOf Worker_DoWork to whatever other function I want to set as a worker?

Comment: @GregHesp: You could, but that might get confusing to maintain. My preference has always been treating workers like functions. They should do one thing and one thing well. I did misspeak about the access though. There is read access to global variables from within `DoWork` itself, so it's not inconceivable that you could use a switch inside to determine an action based on a state manager variable (like an enum or something).

Comment: @JoelEtherton I've just updated my code in my post how I believe it should work.  Unfortunately the GUI has locked up still so I doubt its working

Comment: EDIT: Ah I believe its because my worked call other functions which don't use backgroundworkers